# how to provide read permission for repository in azure container service

Tags: azure, entra-id, entra-domain-services

Im new in the ACS, i configured new registry and uploaded docker image there. 
Also i created two tags similar to that : dir1/imagetag and dir2/imagetag. 
As my next use case scenario is to define read access permission on dir1 for user1 only and on dir2 for user2 correspondingly. 
Actually i did not find in the asure menue relevant option to do it. 
how to provide read permission for repository in azure container service?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Access control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication) to a container registry using an Azure Active Directory-backed [service principal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-objects) or a provided admin account.  Run the standard `docker login` command to authenticate with a registry.
[image]

Comment: @GregP does it works?

Comment: i'm looking for answer from different aspect. I would like to  manage the Roles (OWNER and READER) on repository level as well. Repository is sub-directory of the  Registry and i want to grant to user1 role Read on repository named customer1 and   for user2 role Read on customer2. It's means that user2 will not able to access to customer1 repository because his role restriction. How can i manage via ACS registry options?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called scopemap (though it is preview), through this you can create two scopemap, 1 for repo1 with needed permission which will be used by user1 and another one for repo2 which will be have permission like read or whatever you want will be used by user2.

Read the below link, it will solve your problem..

https://zimmergren.net/using-tokens-and-scope-maps-azure-container-registry-acr-repository-level-access-restriction/